Extension Results for fractional Sobolev spaces on manifolds
For open subsets $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with (uniformly) Lipschitz boundary, there is the classical Stein extension Theorem, that there is a continuous linear operator $\mathcal{E}: W^{m, p}(\Omega) \to W^{m, p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, see e.g. Theorem 13.17 in [1].
This result can be extended to fractional Sobolev spaces $H^s(\Omega)$ for $s \in (0, 1)$, see e.g. Theorem 5.4 in [2].
I am wondering whether this result extends to Sobolev spaces on manifolds, in particular boundaries of Lipschitz domains. More precisely, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n, n \geq 2$ be a Lipschitz domain and $\gamma \subset \partial \Omega$ be a  subset of the boundary with again a Lipschitz $(n-1)$-dimensional boundary $\partial \gamma$. Does there exist a continuous linear extension operator $\mathcal{E}: H^s(\gamma) \to H^s(\partial \Omega)$?
My guess is that one can prove that by localisation and following the proof for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case. My question is whether this is a known result and in which references one can find it.
[1] G. Leoni, A First Course in Sobolev Spaces, vol. 181. in Graduate Studies in Mathematics, vol. 181. Providence, Rhode                     Island: American Mathematical                     Society, 2017. doi: 10.1090/gsm/181.
[2] E. Di Nezza, G. Palatucci, and E. Valdinoci, ‘Hitchhikerʼs guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces’, Bulletin des Sciences Mathématiques, vol. 136, no. 5, pp. 521–573, Jul. 2012, doi: 10.1016/j.bulsci.2011.12.004.
